# Why some processes cannot change CPU priority?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager, priority

I'm on older machine and setting priority to Above Normal or High helps to improve performance for certain applications.

Like e.g. for games. I use System Explorer to set priority and set to Permanent so it would always remember it on every boot. But e.g. for this game (Apex Legends) it does not react to any changes and I do not understand what's going on.

[image]

Comment: It's entirely possible the software itself is preventing it.  Have you contacted the developer?

Comment: If CPU time isn’t a concern (significantly less than 100% load), changing priority will not make your program run faster.

Comment: Make sure you run System Explorer as Administrator (right click => "Run as Administrator"). Then tell us if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible that the process is setting and resetting it's own priorities faster than you can see.

Processes can call [SetPriorityClass](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setpriorityclass) to set their own priority. There is one note in that page that mentions preventing your task from hampering system responsiveness:

> The *_PRIORITY_CLASS values affect the CPU scheduling priority of the process. For processes that perform background work such as file I/O, network I/O, or data processing, it is not sufficient to adjust the CPU scheduling priority; even an idle CPU priority process can easily interfere with system responsiveness when it uses the disk and memory. Processes that perform background work should use the PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN and PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END values to adjust their resource scheduling priorities; processes that interact with the user should not use PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN.

It is *possible* that they are following this advice and wrapping their processing tasks in a background priority and when each task completes they reset the priority back to "normal".

If you were going to do that then typically you would store the current value to restore it after, but they might have just assumed that very few users would change the process priority and setting the priority to normal afterwards was fine.

Only the developers can say for certain.